# How to make my NFC app a "trusted app" in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, nfc, windows-phone-8.1

In Windows Phone 8.1 apps can become a "trusted" NFC app if the user wants. My 8.1 Silverlight app is 8.1 enabled. I've used the NFC feature of the app buy is does not show up in the list.

Is there any declaration needed to show up in the "Apps I trust" list?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's up to the user to add the app as a trusted one, it's not something you can do as a developer. Tap your NFC tag, accept the confirmation, then tap again and there should be an option to set the app as a trusted one.